# DateTime.Parse seems to ignore culture

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

So I'm using `DateTime.ToString()` and `DateTime.Parse()` with a few different cultures. I came across this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 8, 30);

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")).Hour);

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")).Hour);
```

The result is:

```
12
0
```

I made a rextester with some more examples that better show the problem: http://rextester.com/XNBV97545

Even if I add the `CurrentCulture` into the Parse function, the result is the same. Any suggestions for how to get around this?

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: @Joe if it's possible, I'd like to avoid using `ParseExact`

Comment: That doesn't even compile for me because `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is readonly

Comment: @juharr Check again: [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah, now I want to know why I get that compile error.

Comment: `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator` and `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator` are an empty string for the de-DE culture; hence the result you're seeing.  Not sure what you're ultimate aim is, but you could create a custom culture based on de-DE but with AMDesignator and PMDesignator set to a value that matches the input you supply.

Comment: @Joe yeah, I'm aware of what the source of the problem is (hence the rextester link I provided with more output) but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to get around it (I'd rather go with your original suggestion of `ParseExact` rather than create custom cultures)

Comment: @juharr `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` was readonly in previous versions of .Net.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller Yeah, just figured that out.

Comment: The fewer times you convert between strings and datetimes, the better. Ideally, you do it once as close as possible to input and then work with datetimes throughout. And then, as close as possible to the point of presentation, you pick an appropriate format and output that. The rest of your code should *just* be working with appropriate data types that don't **have** formats, such as .Net's `DateTime` and avoid unnecessary conversions. The times you convert a datetime into a string *and back* should be, approximately, zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're losing your precision when you first use `ToString`. You need to use a capital H, because you're losing AM / PM.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 8, 30);

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("MMM d, yyyy H:mm tt")).Hour);
```

Alternatively you can specify the culture as `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to maintain AM / PM regardless of the current culture setting.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 8, 30);

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date.ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Hour);
```

Comment: This is because in `de-DE` culture there is no `AM/PM` at all so `tt` format doesn't print anything

Comment: Awesome - that `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` was just the type of solution I was looking for